# Bootstrap Tabs (Javascript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"><?php include 'acclist.php'; ?></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><?php include 'tournamentresults.php'; ?></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried to add jquery code from bootstrap documentation but it did not work. Can someone tell me what jquery code I need to add, please?

[image]

If I click Results nothing happens

jquery I tried to add:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Alon. I have added a code :)

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs"> (It still doesn't work :()

Comment: [Seems to work](http://www.bootply.com/8LfoC1nITm). Do you have any errors in your browsers console?

Comment: You probably didn't include jQuery and/or Bootstrap JS files correctly.

Comment: I have a lot of other bootstrap and jquery code :)

Comment: Maybe you have in your site other divs with the same id (home/profile)

Comment: @vol7ron that's not true. e.preventDefault() in this case prevents only anchor element from going to specified URL. Another thing is that he doesn't need this code when he uses `data-toggle="tab"`.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap documentation says:

> You can activate a tab navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab".

Use `data-target` or `href` attribute to specify targeting container node in the DOM. Only add *bootstrap.js* or the minified *bootstrap.min.js* to your page.  For example:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @NikitaRibakovs,  the tabs is a controls for tab panes. When tabs  works fine,  controlled panes is switched by click on a tab. Make sure that *bootstrap.min.js* is included to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  Make sure you have your CSS/JS in the proper order and ensure you're including the Bootstrap.js.

Also, as others have mentioned, you don't need to force the tab show; in fact, commenting out he JavaScript below will produce the same result.

```js
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show');
  
  console.log('clicked show');
});
```

```css
#home-content {
  background: #eee;
  color: #369;
}

#profile-content {
  background: #369;
  color: white;
}

.tab-pane>div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    <div id="home-content">home</div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <div id="profile-content">profile</div>
  </div>
</div>
```